# How to make wifi extender from Win 10 and 2 wireless cards

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, wireless-extender

Notebook with internal wifi runing on Win10 which has also connected second wifi card. How to make second card "recive" internet and internal wifi card to "transmit" it ?

Thank you

Comment: If the hardware supports it. Windows has supported bridging connections for a long time. It's not extending, per se, but it's halfway there.

Comment: The question is, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried to make wifi AP via windows settings, also the software called mypublicwifi. Both solutions however expecting LAN internet connection to start